# No-mobile change content column for a form

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

I am working with php and bootstrap.

I have two columns, LEFT shows text, RIGHT shows a form: 
Right now, When I am on a desktop I see both columns. 

On a mobile, I want to see the form only.

I managed to create a CSS/Bootstrap to not see the content of the left column when on mobile. Now, I need help to change the form spot: it has to stay on the right when it's on desktop, and go on the left when on mobile.

```
UPDATED VERSION:

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-6">
    <h1 class="title-2 title-3"><span style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 40px;">title </span></h1>
<ul>
 <li ><b>TEXT1</b></li>
 <li><strong>TEXT2</strong></li>
 <li><strong>TEXT3</strong></li>
 <li><strong>TEXT4</strong></li>
</ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
   <form>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <?php echo $form->getElement("first_name")?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $form->getElement("last_name")?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php if($form->getElement("company")):?>
    <?php echo $form->getElement("company")?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if($form->getElement("company_url")):?>
        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->getElement("company_url")?>
        </div>
    </div>                          
     //more form 
    <div class="row submit">
    <?php echo $form->getElement("post_now")?>
    </div>
</form>                         
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="no-mobile">

<h1 class="title-2 title-3"><span style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 40px;">TITLE </span></h1>

<ul>
 <li ><b> TEXT 1 </b></li>
 <li><strong> TEXT 2 </strong></li>
 <li><strong> TEXT 3 </strong></li>
</ul>
</div>



<div class="row">
 <div class="grid_6">
      <?php echo $form->getElement("first_name")?>
 </div>
<div class="grid_6">
      <?php echo $form->getElement("last_name")?>
</div>
</div>
      <?php if($form->getElement("company")):?>
<div class="row">
     <?php echo $form->getElement("company")?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
 <?php if($form->getElement("company_url")):?>
<div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->getElement("company_url")?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
<div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->getElement("email")?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="grid_6">
      <?php echo $form->getElement("password")?>
</div>
<div class="grid_6">
      <?php echo $form->getElement("repeat_password")?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row submit">
       <?php echo $form->getElement("post_now")?>
</div>


body{
  margin:0;
  color:#000;
  font:16px/24px 'Source Sans Pro', Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background:#fff;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust:none;
  min-width:960px;
}
.grid_6{
float:left;
margin:0 1% 0 0!important;
}

.grid_6{
  width:49%;
}

.no-mobile{display:none;}
```

Comment: What's `grid_6`? Is that from zend-framework?

Comment: Can you post the CSS? If we can reproduce the problem you're having, we can better help you.

Comment: I updated with the CSS

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap already provides a way to hide columns at certain breakpoints. You wouldn't have seen it in the grid documentation because it's located in [Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

Use the `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm` classes on the column on the left containing your text. Use `col-sm-12` on the column on the right to make it full screen at small widths. (If you need different breakpoints, use whichever sizes you need instead.)

You can try out the example below by making it full screen and resizing your browser window. At small widths the left column goes away and the right hand column takes up the rest of the space.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-6">
      <p>Your text would go here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <p>Your form goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what your PHP is generating but I'm also going to suggest you use Bootstrap's form classes and to not put content in `row` divs without the use of any `col-` classes. The result would look something like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-6">

      <h1 class="title-2 title-3"><span style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 40px;">TITLE </span></h1>

      <ul>
        <li><b> TEXT 1 </b>
        </li>
        <li><strong> TEXT 2 </strong>
        </li>
        <li><strong> TEXT 3 </strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <?php echo $form->getElement("first_name")?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <?php echo $form->getElement("last_name")?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php if($form->getElement("company")):?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <?php echo $form->getElement("company")?>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <!-- continue with your form -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's working for the text but I don't  understand why the form is not moving

Comment: @NewPassionnate Are you not able to see it work here in my snippet or is it not working when you try to do this in your code?

Comment: the snippet works. when I follow it in my code, my content is hidden, which is good but the form doesn't move

Comment: @NewPassionnate It may have been the way you were using the row tag. I added another example to my answer.

Comment: I changed with updated version and still the same problem. Maybe it's because for my text I use a content manager and for my form I make the change in the code, in the view? I will update my question with what i did